# C++ self made exception handling failure

Tags: c++, exception

I am taking a c++ class and one of the tasks is the following:

they gave us a main program and we had to write the code behind it. Here is that code:

```
vector<int> iv(4);

iv[3]=42;

cout << iv[3] << endl; // prints "42"

try {
    cout << iv[1] << endl; // throw exception
} 
catch (vector<int>::Uninitialized&){
  cout << "Uninitialized vector element!" << endl;
}

return 0;
```

I've come up with this code for the vector template:

```
T* data;
unsigned int size;

public:
    class Uninitialized{};
    explicit vector(int size) {
        data = new T[size];
        this -> size = size;
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            data[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    ~vector() {
        delete [] data;     
    }

    T& operator[](int index) {
        if (index >= size) {
            abort();
        }
        return data[index];
    }

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, const T& t) {
        if (t == 0)
            throw Uninitialized();
        else
            return o << t;      
    }
```

However, the *friend* method is never called, so the exception is never thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You're throwing at

```
iv[3]=42;
```

because at that point, `data[3] == 0`.

Remember, even in your assignment you're calling `operator[]`; it doesn't care (or even know) if you want the `T&` for reading or writing.

You should approach this kind of problem (and,  in general, problems where the code is simple enough and you know how to make the bug appear) by stepping through it with a debugger first. You would have caught this -- you'd immediately see that the exception isn't being thrown where you think it is.

Comment: You're completely right and it was a rookie mistake to look over that.

Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

When your code runs `iv[3] = 0`, which is outside the `try` .. `catch`, it will throw an exception because `iv[3]` is zero at that point.

You need to tell when an assignment has happened to an element. I suspect your best bet is to return a proxy class from `operator []`, which then has operators for assignment and converstion to `T`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. 
I've looked into it, but I'm afraid we haven't looked at proxy classes during our c++ course. I'm trying to solve it by throwing the exception only when I'm trying to print the result, but now (in the changed code) the method I've used for this is never called and I can't find why.

Comment: It's not really that complex. Imagine you return an object of some new class. Then what operations does that class need in order for your original source to work?